# Retrieving the three highest values in each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

There is a table with the name 'purchase_history' that contains data as shown below:

```
ID          product           price
123           abcd          1000
123           aaaa          2000
123           aaaa          3000
456           yyyy          50
456           bbbb          6000
456           cccc          450
```

I'd like to extract the product name and the amount for the highest 3 prices for each user.
I want to have exactly one output row for each user (even if the made less than 3 purchases) with fields user_id, product_name_1, amount_1, product_name_2, amount_2, product_name_3, amount_3

Any ideas how I can achieve this result?

Comment: Please use CTE (with clause) rather than plaintext tables to specify your input data. Or prepare dbfiddle. It helps to concentrate on answer instead of text formatting. Also specify expected output for your sample input. What is amount? Is it the count of same product? Is the price of product `aaaa` in your example 5000?

Comment: Google "three highest per group sql"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to filter the top 3 prices for each user and then use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.id,
  max(case when t.rn = 1 then product end) product_name_1, 
  max(case when t.rn = 1 then price end) amount_1,
  max(case when t.rn = 2 then product end) product_name_2, 
  max(case when t.rn = 2 then price end) amount_2,
  max(case when t.rn = 3 then product end) product_name_3, 
  max(case when t.rn = 3 then price end) amount_3
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by price desc) rn 
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn <= 3
group by t.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/udpDiMXgAajBfY6B75WoKc/0).
Results:

```
| id  | product_name_1 | amount_1 | product_name_2 | amount_2 | product_name_3 | amount_3 |
| --- | -------------- | -------- | -------------- | -------- | -------------- | -------- |
| 123 | aaaa           | 3000     | aaaa           | 2000     | abcd           | 1000     |
| 456 | bbbb           | 6000     | cccc           | 450      | yyyy           | 50       |
```

Answer (score 1):

use row_number()

```
select a.* from     
(select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by price desc) rn
from table_name
) a where a.rn=1
```

or

```
  select a1.* from table_name a1
  where a1.price=( select max(price) from table_name a2
                 where a1.id=a2.id)
```

or distinct on in postgrey

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, product,price
FROM table_name
ORDER BY id,price DESC
```